# Custom prometheus query with k8s for HPA

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, hpa

I want to do Horizontal pod autoscaling on the basis of input request. I made query for prometheus which returns aggregated input tps.

```
sum(sum by (path) (rate(dapr_http_server_request_count{app_id="governor",path=~"/v1.0/invoke/app/method/interceptor/.*"}[10s])))
```

I want to use this output in kubernetes HPA.

I am using prometheus-adapter for the same. Prometheus configuration is as follows:

```
 default: true
  custom:
    - seriesQuery: '{__name__=~"dapr_http_server_request_avg_.*",namespace!="",pod!=""}'
      resources:
        overrides:
          namespace:
            resource: namespace
          pod:
            resource: pod
      name:
        matches: "^(.*)_total"
        as: "${1}_per_second"
      metricsQuery: 'sum(sum by (path) (rate(dapr_http_server_request_count{app_id="governor",path=~"/v1.0/invoke/app/method/interceptor/.*"}[10s])))'
```

When i try to get the output in custom api of kubernetes it returns.

```
kubectl get --raw "/apis/custom.metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1/namespaces/app/pods/*/dapr_http_server_request_avg_total" | jq .

Error from server (NotFound): the server could not find the metric dapr_http_server_request_avg_total for pods
```

Comment: What k8s version are you using? Does the proposed solution work fro you?

Answer (score 0):

You should check your  prometheus-adapter config file, which makes me confused.

```
seriesQuery: dapr_http_server_request_avg_.*
metricsQuery: dapr_http_server_request_count
```

It is possible to get metrics `dapr_http_server_request_count` from above series?

```
      name:
        matches: "^(.*)_total"
        as: "${1}_per_second"
```

and here take care, your metric name seems to be renamed, you should find the right metric name for you query.

try this: `kubectl get --raw /apis/custom.metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1`

you will see what your K8s Api-server actually get from Prometheus Adapter.